# Conrad Strughold, after The X-Files film and Season 6

Tags: the-x-files

**Conrad Strughold** was one of the highest-ranking members of the Sydicate (aka "the Project") that involved the Cigarette-Smoking Man, the Well-Manicured Man, and others who chose to

> collaborate with the alien colonists as a means of survival.

Strughold seems to be a German national and industrialist of some influence.  He is likely the founder or heir of a mining conglomerate, the *Strughold Mining Co.*, which plays a key role at one point in the show.  The name "Strughold" is first introduced in the Season 3 episode "Paperclip", when Mulder and Scully visit the West Virginia operations of Strughold's company, where

> files on US smallpox vaccine recipients are housed in old mining tunnels.

Strughold himself seems to remain strictly outside the US.  We encounter him in the (first) X-Files film, where he

> meets with other Syndicate members in London to assess the threat posed by the second generation of the black oil (which gestates a biological entity inside its host).

At the end of the film, he

> is in Tunisia, supervising the expansion of the Syndicate's operations in agriculture and bee husbandry.

Given the rapid turn of events in the Season 6 episode "One Son", it is unlikely that Strughold travelled to the US to

> meet his demise with the other Syndicate members at the airforce base.  (Certainly, we do not see him amongst the group that is attacked by the alien rebels.)

I do not believe that Strughold is referred to again in the show.

**Is there any information in extended media (interviews, novels, novelizations, comic books) regarding the fate of Conrad Strughold?**

Pursuant to this, in Season 7, we see the Cigarette-Smoking Man's attempts to

> rebuild the US side of the Syndicate, with Alex Krychek and Marita Covarrubias in assistance.  As part of this, we learn that Alex Krychek had been captured in Tunisia, after his divergence from the Syndicate in "One Son".  Is there any evidence that he was working for (or against) Strughold prior to his detention?  Given Strughold's resources and influence, the Smoking Man may have viewed him as a competitor, and sent Krychek overseas to undermine Strughold's operations.  Is there any information out there regarding Krychek's time in Tunisia and possible interactions with Strughold?

Finally, **what became of Strughold and his international arm of the Project after the**

> **rise of the** ***supersoldiers***?

Comment: Almost 11 months after asking, I think we can conclude that no-one remembers what on earth was going on in *The X-Files*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : Which is why I (more or less) stopped asking *X-Files* questions.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've asked this question many times, and I think the answer is quite simple -- Chris Carter was psyched to cast well established "movie stars" in the first film and thus created the character of Strughold as a "super villain" for the big screen.

Other TV-to-film adaptations like Star Trek: First Contact would retcon previous episodes to make way for a cinematic menace (in this case the Borg Queen) to give the film more weight.

Armin Mueller-Stahl was a recent Oscar Nominee and adept to playing villains, so he was ideal. It's a shame because I think he was one of the scarier villains on the series, given his cold nature and clear ties to the Nazi Regime, he *should* have been revealed as the man behind the further conspiracy later on to show his resolve hadn't been shaken. Clearly he hated Mulder and wanted him stamped out, so it would've been cool to see him truly go after Fox later in the series.

But, in the end, Carter opted to just kill off the Syndicate and be done with the whole arc.

Comment: @John : Thanks for your comments.  Do you have anything to back up the notion that Strughold may have been killed off like the rest of the Syndicate?  As far as I know, there's no evidence that he rendezvoused with at the airforce base where they were killed.  The supersoldiers may have tracked him down, but I don't recall a specific statement to that effect.